# Late binding compile error: User-defined type not defined referencing Outlook mailitem in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, vba, outlook

I am using late binding from Excel.

I get

> Compiler Error: User defined type not defined

for:

```
If TypeOf olMail Is MailItem Then
```

I declare the following variables:

```
Dim olApp As Object
Dim olNs As Object
Dim Fldr As Object
Dim olItms As Object
Dim olMail As Object

Set olApp = CreateObject("Outlook.Application")
Set olNs = olApp.GetNamespace("MAPI")
Set Fldr = olNs.GetDefaultFolder(olFolderInbox)
Set olItms = Fldr.Items
```

The code was working but I had to change to late binding because a user is not using the same Outlook version.

Comment: Side note: Since you're using late binding, you'll need to replace the constant olFolderInbox with the actual value, which would be 6.

Comment: Thank you very much Domenic. You were correct I had to change to a 6. I did not know I had to do this for late binding, as I thought once I had changed the set olApp that the rest would fall into place! How did you know that it needed changing?

Comment: The constant is defined within the Outlook object library.  As such, without a reference to the library, the constant can't be resolved at compiled time, hence the error.  So the actual value needs to be used.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm guessing the reason you get the error is because you no longer have a reference to the outlook object library, and thus `MailItem` is an unknown type.

Instead of using `TypeOf`

```
If TypeOf olMail Is MailItem Then
```

use the `TypeName` function to compare the object type name to a string...

```
If TypeName(olMail) = "MailItem" Then
```

(note I'm assuming the type name will be `MailItem`, but you can always throw in `MsgBox TypeName(olMail)` just to be sure!)

Comment: Thank you very much for explaining and it worked perfectly!

Answer (score 1):

Type Name function is somewhat expensive. `Class` property (implemented by all OOM objects) would be a better aalternative. Check that `oMail.Class = 43` (43 is `OlObjectClass.olMail` constant)